How can I make the signs of terms alternate?

Above you can see the image of the formula I'm trying to solve with Python. Here the user should put a value "X" and then, at the end of the program, the sum of this formula should appear.
The exponent will be 25 at first, decreasing 1 by 1, until 1. The dividend will be 1, increasing 1 by 1, until 25. The first fraction will be a subtraction with the second, the second will be a sum with the third one, and so follows.
#By now, I could only discover how to do this formula adding the values, but not intercalating          #between sum and subtraction. 

x = int(input("X: "))

total = 0
for i in range (25 + 1):
    exp = 25 - i
    div = i + 1
    sum = (x ** exp)/div
    total += sum
print(f"The total is {total:.2f} ")


Note that it's much more efficient to keep a running product than to compute a new power each time through the loop. Each numerator, starting with numerator = -1, is just the previous numerator times -x.
total = 0
numerator = -1
for denominator in range(25, 0, -1):
    numerator *= -x # x, -x*2, x**3, ..., -x**22, x**23, -x**24, x**25
    total += numerator / denominator
    


If the range is even (i.e. range(24, 0, -1)) then this gives the wrong answer as you are summing from x**1 - x**2 + ...  - x**24 and the signs are reversed (rather than summing x**24 - x**23 + ...  - x**1). It will work if the range is odd. You can fix it by using numerator = (-1)**25.

If you want efficient, maybe negate x only once instead of 25 times.

Negation takes no time at all, there's no need to optimize that much.

@JohnKugelman Not true, it does take a little time. And it's one of only four operations in this loop.

To swap the signs, use (-1)**i:
x = int(input("X: "))

total = 0
for i in range (25):
    exp = 25 - i
    div = i + 1
    sign = (-1)**i
    total += sign * (x ** exp) / div

print(f"The total is {total:.2f} ")

or:
x = int(input("X: "))
total = sum((-1)**i * x**(25-i) / (i+1) for i in range(25))
print(f"The total is {total:.2f} ")


Alternatively, set a sign variable and negate it each loop iteration:
total = 0
sign = 1
for i in range (25):
    exp = 25 - i
    div = i + 1
    total += sign * (x ** exp) / div
    sign = -sign

print(f"The total is {total:.2f} ")


If you want to use integers during the sum (and only use a decimal value for the final total, which will help prevent rounding errors during the cumulative sum) then use:
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import Decimal

num_terms = 25
numerator = (-1) ** num_terms * -x
total = Fraction(0)
for i in range(num_terms, 0, -1):
    f = Fraction(numerator, i)
    total += f
    numerator *= -x

print(f"The total is {Decimal(total.numerator)/total.denominator:.2f} ")


You may use i to know if you should subtract or add :
x = int(input("X: "))

total = 0
for i in range (1, 26): # From 1 to 26 (excluded)
    exp = 26 - i
    div = i
    sum = (x ** exp)/div
    total += (- sum if i % 2 == 0 else sum) # even = subtract, odd = add

When i is odd, add, when it's even, subtract.
x:1 = 0.71
x:4 = 1004949214548804.25

